# Дан текстовый файл. Удалить из файла все однобуквенные слова и лишние пробелы. Результат записать в другой файл

Tags: java, файлы, запись

Как записывать данные из файла в другой файл, я знаю, но вот с остальным у меня проблемы:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("D://11.txt");
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D://12.txt")) `{`
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
            // считываем буфер
            fin.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            // записываем из буфера в файл
            fos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *с остальным у меня проблемы* С чем именно? Не узнали у преподавателя, что в задании считается словом? Не узнали, как определить, что пробел - лишний? что-то ещё?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Часть с чтением/записью в файл пропущу, у вас она уже есть.

```
public byte[] replace(byte[] bytes) {

    String input = new String(bytes);    
    input = input
        .replaceAll("\\b[a-zA-Z]\\b", "") //убираем все однобуквенные слова
        .replaceAll("\\s+", " "); // и лишние пробелы

    return input.getBytes();    
}
```

Можно вместо `\\b[a-zA-Z]\\b` написать `\\b[a-zA-Z]\\b(.)?` тогда также удалятся знаки препинания, если вдруг они встречались после однобуквенного слова

Answer (score 0):

На коленке

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f1 = new File("1.txt");
        File f2 = new File("2.txt");

        try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f1); OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f2)) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f1.length()];
            fis.read(bytes);
            bytes = format(bytes);
            fos.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
           System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static byte[] format(byte[] bytes) {
        String s = new String(bytes);

        s = s.replaceAll("\\b\\p{L}\\b", " "); // ищет места, где идет пробел, потом буква,
                                               // потом пробел (или знак препинания) и меняет на " "

        s = s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " "); //ищет места, где 2 и больше
                                          //проеблов и заменяет их на " "

        return s.getBytes();
    }
}
```

Comment: После слова может идти не пробел, а знак препинания. И перед тоже. О переводах строки я вообще молчу

Comment: Почему-то не работает, программа просто удаляет пробелы и всё

Comment: @ЭрнанКортес поправил ответ

Comment: @ Valentyn Anzhurov, работает уже намного лучше, но часть однобуквенных слов по какой-то причине не удаляет

Comment: @ЭрнанКортес дайте пример того, что не удаляет

Comment: @ Valentyn Anzhurov, один из символов f, в строке: vb r  t  f  u  sd  er and f f

Comment: @ЭрнанКортес правил

Comment: @ЭрнанКортес, обратите внимание на ответ Mairenn. Он правильный, за исключение того, что работает только с английскими буквами. Мой вариант работает с любым языком